# Forth, Hofstadter Q Sequence with Recursion

Tags: recursion, sequence, forth, gforth, oeis

I'm attempting to implement [Hofstadter's Q Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence#Hofstadter_Q_sequence) using the recursive definition:

```
Q(1) = 1
Q(2) = 1
Q(n) = Q(n - Q(n-2)) + Q(n - Q(n-1)) for n > 2
```

I get the wrong result for `n > 3`. Here's what I have so far:

```
: Q recursive
    dup 3 <
    if
        drop 1
    else
        dup dup 2dup 2 - Q - Q -rot 1- Q - Q +
    then ;
```

**Try it online:** http://ideone.com/PmnJRO (Edit: Now has the fixed, correct implementation)

I think it doesn't work because there are values added to the stack after each call of `Q` where `n` is greater than `2`, making `-rot` not work as I expected.

Is there a simple adjustment to make this work? Or do I need to use a different approach, maybe using a variable for `n`?

OEIS: [A005185](http://oeis.org/A005185)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized my mistake. I didn't need to preserve `n` after calling `Q`, but I had used `dup` enough times to preserve it each call. This left `n` on the stack after each call, making the output incorrect. I removed one of the `dup`'s and it works.